# Action is not called after being canceled redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I'm cancelling a saga action when CANCEL_SEARCH is called:

```
    function* cancelWorkerSaga(task) {
      console.log(task);
      yield cancel(task);
    }

    export default function* sagaFlights() {
     const workerTask = yield takeLatest(GET_FLIGHTS, getFlights);
     yield takeLatest(CANCEL_SEARCH, cancelWorkerSaga, workerTask);
    }
```

The cancel action is working fine but when i navigate to home screen and tried to make a new search the getFlights actions is not being called anymore. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task returned from `takeLatest` is a watcher task that listens for the action `GET_FLIGHTS` to be disptached, not the currently running `getFlights` saga. Since the watcher is parent to the `getFlights` saga, canceling it will cancel `getFlights` as well.

To avoid canceling the watcher, you can either replace `takeLatest` with a custom loop so you have access to the fork task of `getFlights` or you can put one more saga in between to handle the cancellation:

```
export default function* sagaFlights() {
    yield takeLatest(GET_FLIGHTS, function*(...args) {
        yield race([
            call(getFlights, ...args),
            take(CANCEL_SEARCH)
        ]);
    });
}
```

If you are going to need this pattern often, you can create a simple utility function to hide the logic:

```
const cancelable = (saga, cancelAction) => function*(...args) {
  yield race([call(saga, ...args), take(cancelAction)]);
};

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_A, cancelable(getA, CANCEL_A));
  yield takeLatest(GET_B, cancelable(getB, CANCEL_B));
}
```